# error[3419]: TypeError: Cannot call function via contract type name

Tags: solidity

I'm running into this compiler error when I compile my solidity code:

```js
error[3419]: TypeError: Cannot call function via contract type name.
```

Here is my code:

```
import "MyContract.sol";
.
.
.
MyContract myContract = new MyContract();
address contractAddress = MyContract.deployContract("SimpleStorage");
```

What's going on?

`MyContract` is another contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call a function on an instantiation and not the contract class itself.

Change `address contractAddress = MyContract.deployContract("SimpleStorage");` -> `address contractAddress = myContract.deployContract("SimpleStorage");`

You want to use the variable name, not the class name.

For me, it was as simple as changing the case since the names were so similar:

```
myContract
```

vs

```
MyContract
```